# Cassandra : Getting read count for Index table in cassandra?

Tags: java, nosql, cassandra, hector, astyanax

I wanted to measure if my indexes are really being used or not , basically i would like to drop my secondary index if they are not being used.

Is there a way i can see the read count of index column family which Cassandra internally creates for each index.

### Q:-1 how can i view/list the index column family for my indexes?

### Q:-2 how can see the read count of index column family ? Will the read count tell me all the reads which have happened since the creation of this column family ? If my data is always in memtable will still the read count of index column family gets updated ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do it using jmx beans in Cassandra.

> org.apache.cassandra.db.IndexedColumnFamilies